# PHP: How to Post date in URL after selecting date in jQuery DateRangePicker?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using **jQuery DateRangePicker in PHP** with one selected date only - [Calender UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ6JC.jpg) and trying to **fetch data** from my **MongoDB collection**, whenever I select date its value will be alerting and after alerting value should be call in **place of $currentdate in $filter = ['date' => $currentdate]**, but filter is define above jQuery code.

**PHP Code**

```
$filter = ['date' => $currentdate];
```

**HTML Code -**

```
   <div class="text-right mr-2">
<div class="header-date py-3 text-right">
<span id="reportrange"><i class="icofont-calendar"></i></span>
 <input type="hidden" id="hidreportrange"> 
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', (e, picker) => { 
           var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
           alert(startDate);
```

Comment: Is there a specific question?

Comment: How to Post date in URL after selecting date in jQuery DateRangePicker?

Comment: By POST you mean submitting it? Also, you would like to send every time the user changes the date or only after  selecting and submitting?

Comment: yes submitting also Whenever user change date  only after selecting.

Comment: Okay hold on I’ll answer this once I get back on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to embed an event on date selection.

```
$("#dateInput").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

---

### Without Ajax

Now suppose you have this form

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" id="dateInput" class="date">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

To trigger a form submission to `action_page.php` your js will look like this:

```
$("#dateInput").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $("#myform").submit(); // this will submit the form
    }
});
```

---

### With Ajax

While I am not sure to what extended I understood your question. However, I am assuming you trying to check the date against certain logic in the backend. To make it asynchronous (no page refresh) your js will look like the following:

```
$("#dateInput").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/action_page.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: "dateValue=" + dateText,
        success: function(data) {
                   console.log(data); // display backend response on the console
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you but, if you closely check my question description I  have attached a image in which calendar icon so whenever anyone select a date it will post selected date automatically. (not required any submit button)

Comment: Remove then the submit button from your form. Or just drop off the form completely. You can use the Ajax version without the form, simply have a  <input type="text" id="dateInput" class="date"> in your html.

Comment: yes, sorted it thank you, I made some changes `   $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', (e, picker) => { 
               var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
               alert(startDate);` it will alert selected date

Comment: but after selected date how should I put startDate value in $filter = ['date' => $currentdate]; which calls just before jQuery.

Comment: Express in English what you trying to achieve instead of just putting some code without context. What you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to make sure the user does not select a future date, or should it be in a certain range you have predefined already?